# Realm vs sqLite, which one is best for cross-platform application development

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, realm

I am developing **Cross-platform** application using xamarin forms for all ***WindowsPhone, iOS and android*** app.
Those application can work offline also for this I want use database storing information for offline use.
I need your suggestion which database **ORM** I do use for development and which one is best.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Realm doesn't support UWP at this time, so your choice should be obvious. I like realm, but no windows support yet

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have gone through SQLite for now.

Comment: I need to note that UWP support was introduced in 2017 May, so it does support Windows platform now using Xamarin (and NodeJS server-side with the javascript api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the near future i would vote for realm ,but since at the moment they are not stable and missing many key features in Xamarin.Forms, then I would vote for SQLite for now. 
For me to store information I use the [Settings Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin)  for that. But that is because I am lazy at the first place :)

Comment: Thanks. I heard same thing but i was not sure. 
I implemented SQLite for storing offline data, it is easy to use because I am good hands on Code first EntityFramwork. So I prefered SQLite for xamarin.forms development